# document management solution for EE with folder tree upload drag n drop

Tags: assets, file-uploads, file-manager, ftp

I'm looking for a solution that would enable site admins to upload folders and files á la an FTP client or dropbox via a drag and drop interface. I've had a look at assets but it doesn't seem to handle folder and subfolder uploads: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets

Once uploaded a site member would be able to browse and drill down these folders and see the appropriate files. Site admins would have control over which site members have access to which folders.

Is this even possible with EE or should I be looking at another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assets is the most advanced file manager for EE, so if it doesn't do it then there isn't an out of the box solution for EE.